# How do I make an image move when i scroll down?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

Here is an example of what i want to achieve: 
https://www.flambette.com/en/

I have tried to change the css properties of images but that effect does not satisfy my needs. 
I have tried the following code:

```
mydocument.on('scroll',function() {
      if (mydocument.scrollTop() > 10 && mydocument.scrollTop() < 200 ) {
         $('#first').css('top', '320px');
         $('#first').css('left', '215px');
         $('#first').css('transition', '0.5s');
      } 
      else {
         $('#first').css('top', '300px');
         $('#first').css('left', '200px');
         $('#first').css('transition', '0.5s');
      }
});
```

This is supposed to move an image when you scroll between 10 and 200 px.

Comment: like this? https://jsfiddle.net/yaLz1zqz/1/

Comment: @Stuart are you sure it's the right link?

Comment: Oops - https://jsfiddle.net/ashjffcz/

Comment: I understand your confusion. Sorry for not making myself clear... 
What I'm trying to do is achieve this effect: http://jsfiddle.net/MMZ2h/4/

And i want to apply this effect here: http://marioagaj.esy.es/transition/

I just don't know how to mix them together, that's all.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11):

```js
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
var scrollArea = 1000 - windowHeight;
var square1 = document.getElementsByClassName('square')[0];
var square2 = document.getElementsByClassName('square')[1];

// update position of square 1 and square 2 when scroll event fires.
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || window.scrollTop;
  var scrollPercent = scrollTop/scrollArea || 0;

  square1.style.left = scrollPercent*window.innerWidth + 'px';
  square2.style.left = 800 - scrollPercent*window.innerWidth*0.6 + 'px';
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
}

.square {
  position: absolute;
}

.square-1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  top: 600px;
}

.square-2 {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background: black;
  left: 800px;
  top: 800px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="container">
  <div class="square square-1"></div>
  <div class="square square-2"></div>
</div>
```

Hope to help you.

[Here you can see more examples](https://codepen.io/rachsmith/post/how-to-move-elements-on-scroll-in-a-way-that-doesn-t-suck-too-bad) about movable elements and scroll events.