# How to create illustration in CSS and JS on Scroll

Tags: javascript, css

I have seen a website and started thinking how to create a illustration of paper rocket moving in cubic beizer as in https://www.atlassian.com/

website. Help me do it with CSS on scroll. I tried the following code but failed.

```js
$(function() {
    var rotation = 0, 
        scrollLoc = $(document).scrollTop();
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var newLoc = $(document).scrollTop();
        var diff = scrollLoc - newLoc;
        rotation += diff, scrollLoc = newLoc;
        var rotationStr = "rotate(" + rotation + "deg)";
        $(".plane").css({
            "-webkit-transform": rotationStr,
            "-moz-transform": rotationStr,
            "transform": rotationStr
        });
    });
})
```

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="container">
    <img class="plane" src="https://wac-cdn.atlassian.com/dam/jcr:db49283c-bf71-4ec4-b14c-fbc36a121b2f/plane-2.png?cdnVersion=ll" alt="" data-0="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0)" data-1600="transform: translate3d(1600px, 200px, 0)" class="skrollable skrollable-between" style="transform: translate3d(228px, 28.5px, 0px);" width="168" height="36"> 
</div>
```

Comment: `$(".plane")` doesn't seem to match any element

Comment: @haim770 it is the class for img tag, please see this, Thank you

Comment: You can find this example [helpful][1] but you'll have to add Javascript to handle the user scrolling.
  [1]: https://codepen.io/chris-creditdesign/pen/blJty

Comment: Possible duplicate ["How do I make an image move when i scroll down?
"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45822953/how-do-i-make-an-image-move-when-i-scroll-down)

Comment: @Alex Please do not downvote or mark as spam. I just wanted to learn CSS and JS.

Comment: @Madhu I did not downvote or mark as spam. I just notified you that your solution is already out there. :)

Comment: @Alex Thank you, but can you please try it??

Comment: I don't understand.  What is or is not working now?  The plane spins whenever I scroll.

Comment: @zero298 I want the plane to move in the direction as in the website provided(https://atlassian.com) like the projectile motion

Comment: Is anyone there to help me @Alex

Comment: @zero298 you there>

Comment: @haim770 there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the plane to move around, rather than rotate, then you use use `translate3d` instead or rotation.

```js
$(function() {

  function updateTranslation(el, x) {
    const y = (Math.cos(x*0.015) * 50) + 100;
    const tStr = `translate3d(${-x}px, ${y}px, 0px)`;

    $(".plane").css({
      "-webkit-transform": tStr,
      "-moz-transform": tStr,
      "transform": tStr
    });
  }
  var translation = 0,
    scrollLoc = $(document).scrollTop();

  updateTranslation($(".plane"), 0);

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var newLoc = $(document).scrollTop();
    var diff = scrollLoc - newLoc;
    translation += diff, scrollLoc = newLoc;
    updateTranslation($(".plane"), translation);
  });
})
```

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
}

img {
  position: fixed;
 /* transition: transform 100ms ease;*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="container">
  <img class="plane" src="https://wac-cdn.atlassian.com/dam/jcr:db49283c-bf71-4ec4-b14c-fbc36a121b2f/plane-2.png?cdnVersion=ll" alt="" width="168" height="36">
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't get what you said and thanks for your answer

Comment: @Madhu What do you mean?  Does something not make sense?

Comment: the rocket should move in the curve motion like in the website.

Comment: @Madhu like this?

Comment: Yeah, you got it